# WARNING: Argument 2 out of range

Tags: sas

I'm getting the following warning -->

`error of multiple tables can't be assigned '.'`

Below is my code am trying to fetch certain column variables from a library and then checking if the variable values are missing or not. but there is the above-mentioned error.

Would someone please help me figure out why?

```
%macro drop_check(dsn1=,lib2=,dsn=);
%local rc dsid result;

proc sql noprint;
    select distinct catx(".",libname,memname), name into :list2, :varname separated by " "
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname = upcase("&lib2") and format =('YYMMDD10.');
quit;

%put &list2;

data &dsn(keep=&varname);
    set &list2;
&varname=.;
run;
%MEND drop_check;

%drop_check(dsn1=sample,lib2=grp,dsn=er2);
```

Comment: Based on your description, I'm not sure why you're trying to use VARNUM(), which returns the variable's position in the data set definition (the variable number shown in PROC CONTENTS).  What is it you're trying to find?  Whether or not any of those variables have a missing value in their respective sets (and set `result` accordingly)?  In your example as is, VARNUM() is likely failing because it expects one and only one variable name (and you're providing a list of space-separated variables names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error is that `VARNUM()` does not accept a list of variable names, but that is what you're using. `&VARNAME` is a *list* of variable names from the SQL query.

Another important issue: the `SELECT ... INTO` does not capture the entire list of dataset names because the `SEPARATED BY` instruction only applies to `:varname`.

So your DATA step is not concatenating all the datasets, just the first one. You need to add `SEPARATED BY` to the first macro variable as well.

Most importantly, I do not understand what you are trying to do. If you want to know which columns with that format exist in the library, you already have that because the SQL query lists all of the datasets and columns with that format.

So I have posted corrected PROC SQL code. And you know why your `VARNUM()` error occurred. Maybe you can take it from there.

If you clarify exactly what you're trying to accomplish, I'm sure we can help further.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select distinct catx(".",libname,memname), name into :list2 separated by " ", :varname separated by " "
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname = upcase("&lib2") and format =('YYMMDD10.');
quit;
```

[Added 2016-12-13]

Okay, I'm guessing that the following will do what you want. You can modify it to do other things.

There are many ways to accomplish this, I just picked one. `CALL EXECUTE()` in this case simply acts as a code generator, though it also has the ability to resolve macros and macro variables. If you're familiar with JavaScript, it is similar to `document.write()` as I'm using it.

It seemed reasonably efficient to create a working table from the SQL dictionary rather than trying to use a macro list. In most cases, the dictionary will not be large enough to be a problem, especially when selecting only datasets having variables that use a specific format.

I assumed what you really want is to set the values to missing in the individual datasets, so this example generates a `DATA` step for each dataset that has any variables having the specified format. You can copy them back to the original library if you want to keep them permanently.

```
%macro drop_check(lib2,format=YYMMDD10.);

    proc sql noprint;
        create table vars as
            select distinct libname, memname, name as varname
            from dictionary.columns
            where libname = upcase("&lib2") and format="&format"
            order by libname, memname;
    quit;

    data _null_;
        set vars;
        by libname memname;
        if first.memname
         then do;
            call execute("data " || memname || ";");
            call execute(" set " || strip(libname) || "." || strip(memname) || ";");
         end;
        call execute(varname || "=.;");
        if last.memname
         then call execute("run;");
    run;

%MEND drop_check;

options mprint symbolgen;

%drop_check(sashelp,format=DATETIME.)
```

The invocation above, using the SASHELP library and looking for the DATETIME. format, produced the following results. I verified that the variables were set to missing.

```
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   proc sql noprint;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable LIB2 resolves to sashelp
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable FORMAT resolves to DATETIME.
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   create table vars as select distinct libname, memname, name as varname
from dictionary.columns where libname = upcase("sashelp") and format="DATETIME." order by
libname, memname;
NOTE: Table WORK.VARS created, with 6 rows and 3 columns.

MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   quit;
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.07 seconds
      cpu time            0.07 seconds


MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   data _null_;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   set vars;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   by libname memname;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   if first.memname then do;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   call execute("data " || memname || ";");
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   call execute(" set " || strip(libname) || "." || strip(memname) || ";");
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   end;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   call execute(varname || "=.;");
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   if last.memname then call execute("run;");
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   run;

MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   data VCATALG ;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   set SASHELP.VCATALG;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   created =.;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   modified =.;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   run;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   data VEXTFL ;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   set SASHELP.VEXTFL;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   modate =.;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   run;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   data VSTYLE ;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   set SASHELP.VSTYLE;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   crdate =.;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   run;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   data VTABLE ;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   set SASHELP.VTABLE;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   crdate =.;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   modate =.;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK):   run;
NOTE: There were 6 observations read from the data set WORK.VARS.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


NOTE: CALL EXECUTE generated line.
1   + data VCATALG                         ;
2   +  set SASHELP.VCATALG;
3   + created                         =.;
4   + modified                        =.;
5   + run;

NOTE: There were 17212 observations read from the data set SASHELP.VCATALG.
NOTE: The data set WORK.VCATALG has 17212 observations and 10 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.15 seconds
      cpu time            0.14 seconds


6   + data VEXTFL                          ;
7   +  set SASHELP.VEXTFL;
8   + modate                          =.;
9   + run;

NOTE: There were 21 observations read from the data set SASHELP.VEXTFL.
NOTE: The data set WORK.VEXTFL has 21 observations and 9 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


10  + data VSTYLE                          ;
11  +  set SASHELP.VSTYLE;
12  + crdate                          =.;
13  + run;

NOTE: There were 54 observations read from the data set SASHELP.VSTYLE.
NOTE: The data set WORK.VSTYLE has 54 observations and 4 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.17 seconds
      cpu time            0.17 seconds


14  + data VTABLE                          ;
15  +  set SASHELP.VTABLE;
16  + crdate                          =.;
17  + modate                          =.;
18  + run;

NOTE: There were 1188 observations read from the data set SASHELP.VTABLE.
NOTE: The data set WORK.VTABLE has 1188 observations and 41 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.31 seconds
      cpu time            0.29 seconds
```

[Added 2016-12-15]

Going back the OP and modifying the `PROC SQL` step a little, I have produced something that looks like what I think you asked for:

```
%macro drop_check2(lib2,dsn,format=YYMMDD10.);

    proc sql noprint;
        select distinct catx(".",libname,memname), name 
            into :dsns separated by " ", :varname separated by " "
            from dictionary.columns
            where libname = upcase("&lib2") and format="&format"
            order by 1;
    quit;

    %if &sqlrc NE 0
     %then %do;
        %put PROC SQL returned a warning or error. Terminating macro.;
        %goto mout;
     %end;
     %else %do;
        %if &sqlobs LE 0
         %then %do;
            %put PROC SQL did not return any rows. Terminating macro.;
            %goto mout;
         %end;
         %else %do;
            %local olddsn curdsn curvbl i;
            data &dsn.;
                set 
            %let olddsn=;
            %do i=1 %to &sqlobs;
                %let curdsn=%scan(&dsns,&i,%str( ));
                %let curvbl=%scan(&varname,&i,%str( ));
                %if &curdsn NE &olddsn
                 %then %do;
                    %if &olddsn NE
                     %then %do;
                        )
                     %end;
                    %let olddsn=&curdsn.;
                    &curdsn (keep=&curvbl
                 %end;
                 %else %do;
                    &curvbl
                 %end;
            %end;
            );
            %do i=1 %to &sqlobs;
                %scan(&varname,&i,%str( ))=.;
            %end;
            run;
         %end;
     %end;

%mout:
%MEND drop_check2;

options mprint;

%drop_check2(sashelp,er2,format=DATETIME.)
```

This produces the following data step:

```
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK2):   data er2;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK2):   set SASHELP.VCATALG (keep=created modified ) SASHELP.VEXTFL (keep=modate )
SASHELP.VSTYLE (keep=crdate ) SASHELP.VTABLE (keep=crdate modate );
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK2):   created=.;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK2):   modified=.;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK2):   modate=.;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK2):   crdate=.;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK2):   crdate=.;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK2):   modate=.;
MPRINT(DROP_CHECK2):   run;

NOTE: There were 17212 observations read from the data set SASHELP.VCATALG.
NOTE: There were 14 observations read from the data set SASHELP.VEXTFL.
NOTE: There were 54 observations read from the data set SASHELP.VSTYLE.
NOTE: There were 1180 observations read from the data set SASHELP.VTABLE.
NOTE: The data set WORK.ER2 has 18460 observations and 4 variables.
```

You will see that the output dataset/table contains only the 4 variables/columns but contains a row for every observation in each of the input datasets/tables). If there are variables/columns with the same name in more than one input dataset/table, then those are set to missing more than once, but that's just a little inefficiency.

More to the point, if a duplicate variable/column has different attributes in the datasets/tables in which it appears, it will have the attributes from the first dataset/table.

There is also no way to identify the rows because there are no variables/columns containing identifiers or keys, but this appears to be what you asked for.

Comment: @user7108488, I have added what I think is a bare-bones solution to your question.

Comment: @user7108488, you will need to give a better explanation. The `DATA` statement in your question creates a dataset containing **only** the variables that have the given format, so you end up with a dataset containing nothing but missing values.

Comment: @user7108488, please see if this is what you're looking for.